# CNAME with SSL on Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, load-balancing, cname

Edited the question to articulate better.

I am creating an internal website that will be used by internal company employees. My requirement is that all employee machines should be able to get valid https connection on the application. Below is what I am doing:

1. Create an internal ALB listening on port 443 behind which all front
   end servers are sitting.
2. Create a wild card certificate
3. Map the certificate to ALB
4. Create a private hosted zone
5. Create a CNAME in Hosted zone for ALB.
6. Distribute https://CNAME.com as application url to internal
   employees.

Will this work? Or i will need a client certificate to be installed on internal employees machine? Anything else i may be missing?

Comment: Your ALB is an internet-facing one. There is no way to connect to it privately. In order to achieve your requirement, you need an additional internal LB.

Comment: @jellycsc ALB is internal, in private VPC, edited the question accordingly.

Comment: So `cname.abc.com` is in private hosted zone in R53 if the ALB is internal?

Comment: @Marcin -yep thats correct.

Comment: Can you clarify your setup. How customers can access your internal ALB using private hosted zone? Its not available over internet. Do your custmers use VPN to access your VPC?

Comment: @Marcin - that is my problem statement. My ALB is internal mapped with SSL cert. behind which sit frontend servers. Now the requirment is to enable internal customers enable access application via CNAME. Should the CNAME be public with another load balancer or there is a way to work out with CNAME with private hosted zone?

Comment: @Marcin - please note my customers are internal too(org employees)